# Start an app automatically on device start with react native

Tags: android, react-native, devise

I am learning `react native` and to do so, I am building my first app.
However as great as it is, It seems like react native has some limitations.

What I want my app to do is start running in the background as soon as the device boots up (like WhatsApp or the alarm app).

And I also want notifications like WhatsApp's new message notification (overlaying the screen).

I did it with Android Studio and wanted to do it with react native. So far I have not found any package/library that can do that, is this the limit of `react-native` or is there a package that can do that? Right now I am thinking of going back to native with `android studio`.

Comment: 3 years later, I'm wondering whether someone has an answer for this yet?!

Comment: Me too! I just asked a more specific question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73129627/starting-an-expo-react-native-app-automatically-on-boot-what-to-do-in-the-rece

Answer (score -1):

In android you must ask for necessary permissions in manifest. Also in the phone, you must set battery optimization. In Ios this is the hard one. I cannot do it. Your app must be music app or maps app. Thats all i know.