# Starting an expo/react-native app automatically on boot - what to do in the receiver?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, boot

I've figured out how to get android to run some Java code on the systemwide `BOOT_COMPLETED` event. It's not clear to me what I need to do next to start my app in some form. As a novice android developer, I'm not even sure exactly if I can call into the JS side of the app at this point - is it even initialized?

Right now, on my personal device, the app crashes around this code:

```
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, BootUpHandlerService.class);
            context.startService(myIntent);
```

...on the `startService` call, I get a `BackgroundServiceStartNotAllowedException`.

I presume this means I need to call `startForegroundService` instead, but [the android docs say that may not be possible with Android 12](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#startForegroundService(android.content.Intent)).

The docs also seem to suggest [I can start a WorkManager task](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#foreground-service-launch-restrictions). Given all the code I've written to use WorkManager tasks actually does so from javascript through a 3rd party library, I have no clue how to even do that from Java. All of my code to prepare for the work I want to do in the background and initialize the tasks themselves is in the frontend, running in an expo/react-native context. Sure, poor practice, but I can refactor once I understand *what I need to refactor it into*.

While I appreciate what they are doing here as an end user who hates the numerous services running in the background on my phone, it does seem confusing for a novice android developer.

What should I do instead? How do I run JS without the frontend to schedule WorkManager tasks? [The docs seem to say I can't even do that, not even with a "notification trampoline"](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#notification-trampolines).

Comment: It's a more specific form of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47944721/start-an-app-automatically-on-device-start-with-react-native

Comment: Do you want that the activity start running without user interaction or do you want to bring the React level up - e.g index.js listening for events?

Answer (score 1):

In `expo` , go to `app.json` present at root

then in android `intentFilters` object, you can add `MAIN` action with `category` "HOME" like this:

```json
"android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF"
      },
      "package": "com.sample.app",
      "intentFilters": [
        {
          "action": "MAIN",
          "category": [
            "HOME",
            "DEFAULT",
            
          ]
        },
        {
          "action": "MAIN",
          "data": {},
          "category": [
            "LEANBACK_LAUNCHER",
            "LAUNCHER"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
```